# pandas pivot table rename columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, data-mining

How to rename columns with multiple levels after pandas pivot operation?

Here's some code to generate test data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c0': ['A','A','B','C'],
    'c01': ['A','A1','B','C'],
    'c02': ['b','b','d','c'],
    'v1': [1, 3,4,5],
    'v2': [1, 3,4,5]})

print(df)
```

gives a test dataframe:

```
   c0 c01 c02  v1  v2
0  A   A   b   1   1
1  A  A1   b   3   3
2  B   B   d   4   4
3  C   C   c   5   5
```

applying pivot

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["c0"], columns=["c01","c02"], values=["v1","v2"])
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

gives

[image: output1]

how to rename the columns by joining levels?
with format 
`<c01 value>_<c02 value>_<v1>`

for example first column should look like 
`"A_b_v1"`

The order of joining levels  isn't really important to me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to coalesce the multi-index into a single string index without caring about the index level order, you can simply `map` a `join` function over the columns, and assign the result list back:

```
df2.columns = list(map("_".join, df2.columns))
```

---

And for your question, you can loop through the columns where each element is a tuple, unpack the tuple and join them back in the order you want:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["c0"], columns=["c01","c02"], values=["v1","v2"])

# Use the list comprehension to make a list of new column names and assign it back
# to the DataFrame columns attribute.
df2.columns = ["_".join((j,k,i)) for i,j,k in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ```['_'.join(str(s).strip() for s in col if s) for col in df2.columns]``` worked as a general solution, independent of number of levels

Answer (score 4):

If some column names are not strings, you can `map` the column names to strings and `join` them.

```py
df2.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, c)).strip('_') for c in df2]
```

If you want to chain the renaming method to `pivot_table` method to put it in a pipeline, you can do so using `pipe` and `set_axis`.

Moreover, you can also reorder column levels using `reorder_levels`, e.g. `<c01 value>_<c02 value>_<v1>` instead of `<v1>_<c01 value>_<c02 value>`

```py
df2 = (
    df.pivot_table(index=["c0"], columns=["c01","c02"], values=['1','2'])
    .reorder_levels([1,2,0], axis=1)                # makes "v1","v2" the last level
    .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(
        map('_'.join, x)                            # if all column names are strings
        #('_'.join(map(str, c)) for c in x)         # if some column names are not strings
        , axis=1)
         )                                          # rename columns
    .reset_index()
)
```

[image: result]