# Change column headers in pivot table (in pivot command)

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas pivot table option in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
...                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
...                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
...                    "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
...                          "small", "large", "small", "small",
...                          "large"],
...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
...                    "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
 table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D', 'E'], index=['A', 'C'],
...                     aggfunc={'D': 'count',
...                              'E': np.mean})
```

the outcome is:

```
                D   E
A   C       
bar     large   2   7.500000
        small   2   8.500000
foo     large   2   4.500000
        small   3   4.333333
```

How can I change the `pd.pivot_table`command that I have:

```
                Nr.of D     E
A   C       
bar     large   2   7.500000
        small   2   8.500000
foo     large   2   4.500000
        small   3   4.333333
```

Followed by this post it is possible to rename it afterwards  [pandas pivot table rename columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099024/pandas-pivot-table-rename-columns) , but with some more columns it can be tricky to rename it, is it possible to change the name of the `values=['D', 'E']`directly in the `pd.pivot_table` line?

Comment: Use `(table.rename(columns={'D':'Nr.of D'}))`

Comment: in general working, but is there a chance to write it in the pivot_table line?

Comment: No, you can rename column before or after, in pivot_table not