# How to add title and count as column names in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find duplicate values of a dataframe column and its count in descending order.

Able to achieve with below code

```
dfNew = df.pivot_table(index=['Title'],aggfunc='size').sort_values(ascending=False)
```

However, when I print the `dfNew`, the results are coming as expected but the title of columns is blank. How to ensure results display under the Title and count columns

```html
<table>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Australia Beach</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Canada Beach</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099024/pandas-pivot-table-rename-columns

Comment: Can you provide a clear, minimal reproducible input/output example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: am trying to find duplicate values of a dataframe column and its count by descending order.

Able to achieve with below code

dfNew = df.pivot_table(index=['Title'], aggfunc='size').sort_values(ascending=False)

However when i print the dfNew, the results are coming as expected but the title of columns is blank. How to ensure results display under the Title and count columns

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Basically I want to introduce count column as well, since i calculated the count based on the Title column from dataframe. Issue is while displaying datframe, I am getting results (title and respective count) however the respective columns are empty ( i am expecting title and count columns)

Comment: see the table structure above, basically i am missing the column names

Comment: ok finally achieved using below code

dfNew = df.groupby(['Title']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name="count")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataframe you're starting with looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Title": [
        'Australia Beach', 
        'Canada Beach', 
        'Australia Beach', 
        'Canada Beach', 
        'Canada Beach', 
        'Canada Beach', 
        'Canada Beach'
    ]
})
print(df)
```

```
             Title
0  Australia Beach
1     Canada Beach
2  Australia Beach
3     Canada Beach
4     Canada Beach
5     Canada Beach
6     Canada Beach
```

A much simpler way to do it is with `df.value_counts()`:

```
df.value_counts()
```

```
Title          
Canada Beach       5
Australia Beach    2
dtype: int64
```

This function gives you the same output as `df.pivot_table(index=['Title'],aggfunc='size').sort_values(ascending=False)`, but the code is much more concise. It returns a pandas Series object, but it sounds like you want to return a dataframe with `Title` and `Count` as the column names. You can do this simply with the following:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts(), columns=['count']).reset_index()
```

```
             Title  count
0     Canada Beach      5
1  Australia Beach      2
```